# How use environment variable value in build config

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I wanted to know if there is a way to use value from an environment variable in a build config object in Openshift. Just to be clear, I am not looking to define environment variable in build config. I am looking to use value from existing environment variable within scope of build config.

I am using S2I with git a source. In below section on build config, currently BRANCH_NAME is a parameter. So every time, I create new branch, I need to update parameter value. Instead, I want to use environment variable called BRANCH_NAME which is being externally set by the Jenkins build agent. If I am able to use that environment variable, I no longer need to rely on parameter or update it for every new branch.

```
source:
  git: 
    ref: "${BRANCH_NAME}"
    uri: "${SOURCE_REPOSITORY_URL}"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not allowed to comment but do you mean to use the defined env within same config?
Here is a snippet..You can see reference doc for full code

```
env:
    - name: MY_EXISTING_ENV
      value: my_value
    - name: MY_ENV_VAR_REF_ENV
      value: $(MY_EXISTING_ENV)
```

reference:
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.8/nodes/containers/nodes-containers-downward-api.html#nodes-containers-downward-api-container-envars_nodes-containers-downward-api

Comment: Not exactly, what I am looking for. I am using S2I to build the image and using Git as source. Let me update the question so that its easier to have formatted sample to explain what I need.